# Get Table of contents to include "title" style

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office

I know Word automatically generates a table of contents using heading levels 1 and 2.

I was wondering if it was possible to make Word include the Title formatting also?

I am using both Word 2010 and 2007 on a WIndows pc.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - to do this you need to:

### Set the Title style to your desired Outline level so it will be available in the Table of Contents:

1. Open the Styles window (Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S)
2. Scroll down to the Title style and select Modify...
   [image: Word 2007: Modify the Title style]
3. Click the Format button and select Paragraph...
   [image: Word 2007: Format the Paragraph styling]
4. Set the Outline level to your desired level
   [image: Word 2007: Set Outline level]

This will add the Title style to the options available in the Table of Contents builder.

### To verify that the Title style will now be added to the Table of Contents:

1. Choose the References tab
2. Click Table of Contents
3. Choose Insert Table of Contents...
   [image: Word 2007: Insert Table of Contents]
4. Click the Options... button
   [image: Word 2007: TOC Options]
5. Scroll through the Available styles: list to make sure that the Title style now shows up and that it has the desired TOC level
   [image: Word 2007: Verify TOC level]

Comment: That has to be the most detailed answer ever.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 I wish you would work for Microsoft and re-do all of their Office documentation!

Comment: Just dropping by to point out that I had to do the reverse of this to *stop* Title styles from showing up in my TofC.  I'm not sure whether Title style in Word2013 has a level assigned by default or I inherited a mucked-up style from some other document.

Comment: I have some custom styles and when I select my custom style as shown in the 5th step, Table of Contents insists on not to include some of those I have selected from styles list :) do you have any idea, what can it be? and moreover each time I remove default Heading 1, 2, and 3 but when I enter edit field I see them again and again :) Okay it does not have any effect since I have no Heading 1 or 2 or 3 but Word is insisting on keeping them :)

Comment: Paragraph is not an option for me in that dropdown (its greyed out/disabled). Any other ideas on how I can get it in the TOC?