# create a style that is shown in the TOC mac 2011 word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, styles, table-of-contents

how do i create a style in MS Word 2011 for the mac that will automatically be shown in the table of contents, just like header 1,2 etc are. i have tried creating one that is based on header 3, as shown in the picture.

[image]

The style will be used on a sub header of a table. only the sub  header will be in the Table of contents. in the following picture, the cell 'login form' is the sub header i wish to be in the table of contents.[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have just found the answer out myself thanks to this link.

[Get Table of contents to include "title" style](https://superuser.com/questions/256551/get-table-of-contents-to-include-title-style)

The only difference was that this link shows how to put titles in the TOC whereas i wanted the sub header to be under the header 2 level. so all i changed was the outline level to level 3